# Could someone explain how revWord is printed in reverse?

Tags: java

```
String word = "elephant";
String revWord = "";
for (int i = 0; i < word.length(); i++) {
    revWord = word.charAt(i) + revWord;
}
System.out.println("Word: " + word + " in reverse is " + revWord);
```

I know how for loops word and charAt and incrementation

I just don't understand how it reverses it

This is the output:

```
Word: elephant in reverse is tnahpele
```

Comment: What would you expect it to print if it was `revWord = revWord + word.charAt(i);`?

Answer (score 1):

The best way to understand your code is to take a piece of paper and work out each iteration of the loop, until it "clicks" in your own head.  Let's take a three character string input of `ABC` to see what happens:

```
after first iteration:
revWord = A + "" = A

after second iteration:
revWord = B + A = BA

after third iteration:
revWord = C + BA = CBA
```

Basically, at each step of the loop it tags on the next letter to the *front* of the running reverse string.  As you can see above, this has the effect to flip the order of characters in the input word.

Answer (score 1):

it's because of this line:
revWord = word.charAt(i) + revWord;

each time your loop goes pick a char and place it in begining of the revWord.
it mwans the for each time step forward and near to end of String characters place them in first of revWord String